# Simple multiple modal text boxes on single html page

Tags: css, textbox, modal-dialog

I'm a novice / beginner and I am trying to create a html page that has images that when you click on them, a text box pops up and provides information. The text is about 150 - 200 words and I want the pop up boxes to be responsive.

After a lot of time spent on this, the best solution I found (at my beginner level) was to use a modal box with scroll bars (due to the amount of text to read). I have used this code / guide:
http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

and I amended line 8 in the code from absolute to relative because the original version does not allow the scroll bars to scroll to the bottom to read the text fully when I used the code and tried it for myself.

```
.modal {
display: none; /* Hidden by default */
position: relative; /* Stay in place */
```

I have uploaded a version here with the slight amendment.

http://sugastore.com/test/modal-textbox.html

However, I want to have multiple modal text boxes on the same html page and I do not know how to do this. I have been reading online and the information about numbered div ID's but the information has been too advanced for me to understand.

My question is:

**Q1.** How can I use this modal code to create multiple modal boxes on one page? (and for them to be responsive)

Also, but not so important (I am sure I can find a way from reading online, but will ask here as well).

**Q2.** How do I change the link from a button to an image, so you click on an image and the modal box pops up?

**Q3.** When I change the modal from absolute to relative (as detailed above) the semi-transparent black background does not fit the whole page, is there a simple fix to amend this?

I also welcome anyone who already has a script / code example for a simple responsive multiple modal text box pop up (upon clicking an image) that is responsive and allows for scrolling to account for a lot of text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Q1: You can use the code to create multiple modals but you have to give them different ID's. eg #myModal, #myModal1, #myModal2 or better still name them according to what they display. They should be responsive as bootstrap modals are designed to be responsive

Q2: Replace the button tags with image tags and give it the ID "myBtn". Clicking on the image should trigger the modal

Q3: Change the relative to fixed. This should solve the problem.

Comment: thanks for your reply but it doesn't seem to work:

Q1. As soon as I amend line 84 to anything other than the original 'myModal' it stops working.

I've uploaded an example:
http://sugastore.com/test/modal-textbox-hash.html

I presume is this where I change the ID? (line 84 code).

Q2. I didn't really understand this (sorry, beginner!) an example of code would be helpful.

Q3. Changing it to fixed gives me the original problem, the scroll bars do not fully scroll down when you make the window smaller, here's an example:

http://sugastore.com/test/modal-textbox-scroll.html

Comment: Q1: Maybe I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve here. Q2: instead of <button id="myBtn"></button> make it <img id="myBtn"></img>. Q3: What scroll bar?

Comment: thanks for your input, especially for Q2. Q1 - I could not fix the problem and Q3 - the scroll bar for the modal window that allows the user to scroll the modal up and down, however in the end I gave up and instead found another example code to work from and it works - here's the link:
http://sugastore.com/test/multiple-modal-test.html